# Decision making and loop

Tags: java

I am brand new to Java (2 weeks), basically I am trying to do a Triangle problem. I need to input a text file that looks like this:

2 2 2

3 3 2

3 x 4

I can make it read the file and display it correctly, however I need it to display  "Equilateral"  " Isosceles" "Scalene" or not a triangle because... I cannot figure out how to get my outputs based on the input from the text file. Here is what I have so far.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {

    File file =
      new File("input.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine())
      System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
  }
```

}

Which is basically nothing. I know I need 3 arrays. Can someone jumpstart me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you know the formula to determine what kind of triangle the three sides would make. So for each array, follow the formula and print the result. You would probably want to store the sides in an array of arrays

Comment: OK, the two things you need to know are (1) three numbers don't make a triangle if any one of them is greater than or equal to the sum of the other two; (2) a triangle is equilateral, isosceles or scalene depending on HOW MANY different numbers there are among the side lengths.  So you need to work out a strategy for parsing the input, converting `String` values to numbers, checking condition (1) above, then counting how many different numbers there are.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `sc.nextLine()` to a variable to use instead of printing it out as an output immediately. If the sets of three numbers come in a single line, you may want to utilize the `split()` method, which is pretty easy to use when you understand arrays.

To get you started:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {

    File file =
      new File("input.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine())
      String firstLine = sc.nextLine();
      String[] sides = firstLine.split(" ");// Get the numbers in between the spaces
      // use the individual side lengths for the first triangle as you need
      // Next iteration works through the next triangle.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're headed in the right direction. I suggest checking out the following methods:

- `String.split()` [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
- `Integer.parseInt()` [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Those, combined with a little bit of your own logic, should be enough to get you across the finish line.

Comment: Thank you! I will check out the documents